# incluir una carpeta a la compilacion de typescript

Tags: nodejs, typescript, ejs

soy algo nuevo con node js le agregue typescript a mi proyecto.a la hora de transpilar el codigo a js me genera una archivo dist hasta ahi normal,el problema va cuando quiero agregar una carpeta para las vistas,cuando transpilo mi codigo no me agrega esta carpeta dentro de la carpeta dist,alguna solución?

[image: Estructura de la carpeta dist que se genera despues de transpilar typescript]

[image: estructura del proyecto principal]

codigo de la app principal.

```
    import express from "express";
import * as bodyParser from "body-parser"; // used to parse the form data that you pass in the request
import routes from "./routes";
import cors from "cors";
import path from "path";
class App {
  public app: express.Application;

  constructor() {
    this.app = express(); // run the express instance and store in app
    this.config();
  }

  private config(): void {
    this.app.use(cors());
    // support application/json type post data
    this.app.use(bodyParser.json());
    // support application/x-www-form-urlencoded post data
    this.app.use(
      bodyParser.urlencoded({
        extended: false
      })
    );
    this.app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "../public")));
    this.app.set("view engine", "ejs");
    this.app.set("views", __dirname + "../public/views");
    this.app.use(routes);
  }
}

export default new App().app;
```

Answer (score 0):

tengo una solución no muy elegante, pero que es la que estoy usando yo de momento, conozco el problema y ahora pensaba generar en stackoverflow una pregunta parecida.

Para solucionar tu problema es muy sencillo, te cuento como funciona la transpilación: si tienes una carpeta public de salida, y otra src donde creas una carpeta por ejemplo server y dentro un archivo ts, al tener solo creada una carpeta dentro de src todos los archivos que crees dentro de server o dentro de src cuando se trnaspile se generaran en la carpeta public en formato js.
Pero si creas dentro de src dos carpetas y dentro de la segunda carpeta creas un archivo tsc aunque no lo uses después, solo entonces el transpilador generará dentro de la carpeta public las dos carpetas que hay en src con sus archivos generados js.
No me preguntes porque esto es así, lo he descubierto por casualidad, pero funciona, pruébalo.